# Deploy React website with node.js backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have developed website in react and node.js as intermediary to send and receive response.
Now i want to put this on a machine in lab , so everyone can access it.
Can i Install node on machine in lab and run same setup as on my dev machine and give ip of that server?

I tried searching deployment with node js an react, but everyone using AWS, or some external server after npm build.
How do I deploy my react app on lab machine with out actually copying code?

Comment: Do you want to run the app on a machine and every other machines connected on that network want to access it ?

Comment: yes, i want everyone with ip of lab machine to access it

Comment: I think it is possible by sharing the IP of the hosted machine with everyone. The app can be access through the shared IP. (Hope all the machines are connected to the same network)

Answer (score 1):

Two Things before you share your IP and PORT:

> 1. Have a process monitor setup in your lab machine, Check out [pm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2). This will help you run your application in the background,
>      monitor your application and start your application after restart.
> 2. Enable port in your firewall for everyone to use. if your lab system is Ubuntu then allow ufw for the port.

Now you can share your IP:PORT and everyone would be able to access it, provided they all are connected to the same network.

Answer (score 0):

If you want everybody access your server, you can share your private IP with them, so others can access it using

```
yourip:port
```